# Find user by role using spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

My User Entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Every User can have many roles. Given a role (represented in String datatype), I want to get all the users that have this role.

For example

User1 with role : "admin"

User2 with role : "user"

User3 with role : "admin"

For the role "admin", I want to get as a result the User1 and User2.

What I have tried with Spring Data Jpa:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    public List<User> findByRoles( String role);
}
```

But i'm getting an exeption

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role:
>   com.spring.certificatie.securityconfig.User.roles, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve LazyInitializationException in Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507446/how-to-resolve-lazyinitializationexception-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: From the discussion you mentionned, i picked the solution that ask to change from List to Set. And it works fine. But why, there is no explaination from the others discution.

Comment: Must have read a different discussion than I did.

Comment: could you mention the part that explains why Set works weel against the List. I'm not talking about the cause of the exeption. thanks

Comment: Probably not -- you have no example and edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your UserRepository use in this way

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByRolesIn(Collection<String> names, Pageable pageable);
}
```

In your Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/usersByRole/{userRole}")
public List<User> getUser(@PathVariable String userRole, Pageable pageable){
    return userRepository.findByRolesIn(Arrays.asList(userRole), pageable);
}
```

And You will have result like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here from **User** to **Role** is *ONE-TO-MANY* mapping 
i.e list of Roles is an element of **User** entity, and you are passing a `String` as List of Roles.
This is the reason you are getting Exception.

Solutions:

- Use `findByRolesIn(List<String> roles)` instead of `findByRoles(String role)`
- Or, Make one-to-one mapping as below:

  ```
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String role;
  ```
- Or, Use JPA Query or Native query as below.

  ```
  @Query( "select u from User u  where u.roles in :roles" )
  public List<User> findByRoles(@Param("roles") List<String> roles);
  ```