# How to findAll by multplie string values?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, enumeration

I have an entity employee which has `status` field as `@Enumerated` which is being saved as String in `PostgreSQL`.

.

status can contain 3 values: `ACTIVE, INACTIVE, TRIAL`.

I want a JPA method without named query, or `@Query` Annotation which will fetch me all Employees `where status = 'ACTIVE' or 'TRIAL'.` 
.

`findAllByStatusIn(List statusList)' 
gives only the last added status to the list.

i.e., if I add

```
statusList.add(Status.ACTIVE)
statusList.add(Status.TRIAL)
```

.
then I only get `TRIAL` employees
.
But if I add

```
statusList.add(Status.TRIAL);
statusList.add(Status.ACTIVE);
```

How do I get values with both statuses using JPA method?

Any help is appreciated.

New to JPA and Spring data.

Please guide me to the right answer if this question is a possible duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `all` from your method. Should just be `findByStatusIn(List<String> status);`

Comment: can you show more code? how are you calling it? what happens in the case you add trial or active? seems you didn't complete it.

Comment: did you try `findByStatusIn(List statusList)` ?

Comment: `List<Entity> findByStatusIn(List<Status> status)` must work. If it doesn't then you really messed up something somewhere in your config.  (Add the type argument to the `List` too)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57071384/9427395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few versions from the above valuable comments, I found the right method for fetching based on a list of statuses.

```
Page<Employee> findAllByStatusIn(List<Status> statusList, Pageable pageable);
```

works as expected. 
Gives pageable info as well. I also tried by removing `All` keyword from the method.

This too works the same:

```
Page<Employee> findByStatusIn(List<Status> statusList, Pageable pageable);
```

Since it is multiple records fetched at once, I kept the `All` keyword for better understanding.

But I believe it is not really necessary.